# What is the performance cost of primitive-acting structs?

Tags: c#

I'm interesting in getting my numeric types more 'strong' in the sense that, for example, `double` values could be specialized to mean different things. Unfortunately, in C# the best I can come up with is writing something like `using Real = System.Double;` which really isn't useful because there is no static checking.

So I've been thinking about this idea of essentially wrapping numeric types in `struct` values, e.g.:

```
struct Real
{
  double Value;
  public static implicit operator double(Real r) { return r.Value; }
  // and so on
}
```

My question: what are the performance implications of this? Am I taking a significant hit compared to just biting the bullet and using `double`?

**Edit:** what I really want to have is a way of defining more stronly typed numeric variants so that a function `Calculate(Rate rate)` could not be called with an argument of type `Percentage` or even `double`, for that matter.

Comment: Have you done any performance analysis before posting the question? If there is performance impact then we could have helped you in why it's there.

Comment: What do you mean by "more strong" and having doubles "specialized to mean different things?" I have a bad feeling about this.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I imagine it means checking dimensionality and units.  For example, to disallow passing a physical length (in meters) to a function which wants a time interval (in seconds).

Comment: @AmarPalsapure no, thus the question

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I mean something along the lines of 'units of measure' in F# where you can be prevented from mixing incompatible numeric types

Comment: this requirement looks like you want to make very functionnal treatments. Maybe you should just use F# (remember you can call any .Net assembly from F# and call a F#-written assembly from any .Net language).

Comment: F# is tempting but I want ReSharper support.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, there *is* a performance hit to this, yes. You might expect the JIT to be able to effectively make it completely transparent, but I don't believe it does. (Of course different versions of the CLR may well behave differently in this respect, and future versions may improve further.)

Now as to whether this different is *significant* or not, you really need to test it - it'll be entirely application-specific. What are you doing with these values, and how important is it to the overall application performance? What is your *required* performance, and does your application already meet it? If you don't have any measurements in place, that should be your first port of call.

As a point of reference though, in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) we have various structs which just wrap a `long`... but the API benefit from keeping those types distinct (and making them all distinct from just `long`) is *massive*. I care a lot about performance in Noda Time, but I certainly wouldn't change to use `long` everywhere just for the performance boost. It's all a matter of balancing the pros and cons - and we can't judge those for you.

(It's not clear to me whether your question stems from the same sort of wish to treat various values in different ways, even though they're just backed by `double`. I *think* that's what you mean, but it would be worth editing the question to make it clearer.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Right. That's exactly the same sort of thing we're doing in Noda Time. Now, do you have specific requirements, and have you measured whether you can meet them with the cleaner code? Do you know if your performance is even gated by CPU?

Comment: I have no specific requirements, just want a cleaner API. I haven't looked at performance myself, which is why I'm asking others about their observations.